# component not re-rendering when updating the state in mobx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I'm trying to understand why my app is not re rendering when I changing my state in the mobx observable names array.
I'm changing the value with the input tag.
would love for some help :)

observers component:

```
import {observable, action, autorun, computed} from 'mobx'

class TodosStore {
    @observable names = ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
    @observable filter = ""

    @action
    get filterredValue(){
        return store.names.filter(word => word.includes(this.filter))
    }
}

//@ts-ignore
var store = window.store = new TodosStore

export default store


autorun(() => {
    console.log(store.filter); 
    console.log(store.names); 
})
```

and this is my app component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import store from  './components/observers'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props :any) {
    super(props);
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
  }

  setName = (e : any) => {
    store.filter = e.target.value

  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {store.filterredValue.map((name) => <li key={name}>{name}</li>)}
        <input
          onChange={(e) => this.setName(e)}
          />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define things like `observable`, `computed` and `action` in `TodoStore` using [`makeObservable`](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#makeobservable) as [`decorators`](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html#enabling-decorators-) are currently **not** being preferred (decorators are currently not an ES standard, and the process of standardization is taking a long time):

**TodoStore:**

```
import { observable, autorun, computed, makeObservable, action } from "mobx";

class TodoStore {
  names = ["p1", "p2", "p3"];
  filter = "";

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      names: observable,
      filter: observable,
      filterredValue: computed,
      setFilter: action,
    });
    autorun(() => {
      console.log(this.filter);
      console.log(this.names);
    });
  }

  get filterredValue() {
    return this.names.filter((word) => word.includes(this.filter));
  }

  setFilter(filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
  }
}

export const todoStore = new TodoStore();
```

And, here is `App` component using [`observer`](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#observer) (A higher order component which makes a functional or class based React component re-render when observables change):

**App:**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component<any> {
  setName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.props.store.setFilter(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          {this.props.store.filterredValue.map((name) => (
            <li key={name}>{name}</li>
          ))}
          <input onChange={(e) => this.setName(e)} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default observer(App);
```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit my-mobx-react]

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to wrap every component that uses `observable` state into `observer` decorator, like that:

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react'

@observer
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

// or if you are using functional components:

const App = observer(() => {
  // ...
})
```

Also, if you are using MobX version 6 you need to add `makeObservable` call inside class constructor:

```
import {observable, action, autorun, computed, makeObservable} from 'mobx'

class TodosStore {
    @observable names = ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
    @observable filter = ""

    constructor() {
       makeObservable(this);
    }

    @action
    get filterredValue(){
        return store.names.filter(word => word.includes(this.filter))
    }
}
```

[More about MobX and React integration in the docs](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add **shouldComponentUpdate** to your component. Make it **return true** when the state is changed.

Comment: thanks! but I don't want to add new functions to the code, I'm sure there is a different mobx solution to my problem.

Comment: React does not update a component if it's not said to do that explicitly (by changing props or setting state), so you have two options: watch the store change inside the component (somponentShouldUpdate) or pass the stored data to the component via props...  Good luck anyway

Answer (score -1):

You should set `name` and `value` to your input.

```
   <input name="" value="" onChange={(e) => this.setName(e)} />
```

Comment: @blue-sky your answer is good but not related to the problem :)