# Mobx not updating react native element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx

I'm new to react and mobx.
I'm trying to use mobx to update a simple counter and display the count number.
When I click on the button "Add" I can see in the logs that *counterStore.count* is increasing but counter shown in the *<Text></Text>* remains equal to 0.

Can you please me tell me what is wrong?

**index.tsx**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import React from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import CounterStore from './stores/CounterStore';

export function App() {
  const counterStore = new CounterStore(0);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Text>{counterStore.count}</Text>
            <Button
                title="Add"
                onPress={() => {
                    counterStore.addToCount();
                    console.log("count = ", counterStore.count);
                    
                }}
            />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: "100%"
  },
  wrapper: {
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 425
  }
});

export default observer(App);
```

**CounterStore.ts**

```
import { action, makeObservable, observable } from "mobx";

class CounterStore {
  @observable count: number;

  constructor(count: number){
    this.count = count
    makeObservable(this);
  }

  @action
  addToCount(){
    this.count++;
  }
}

export default CounterStore;
```

**Output & Logs**

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMYnu.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [component not re-rendering when updating the state in mobx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034998/component-not-re-rendering-when-updating-the-state-in-mobx)

Comment: No. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I tried to improve my code based on *Jay Vaghasiya*'s answer, but still got the same behaviour.

**CounterStore.ts**

```
import { action, makeObservable, observable } from "mobx";
import React from "react";

class CounterStore {
  count = 0;

  constructor(){
    makeObservable(this), {count: observable};
  }

  @action
  addToCount(){
    this.count++;
  }
}

export const CounterStoreContext = React.createContext(new CounterStore());
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import React from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { CounterStoreContext } from './stores/CounterStore';

const App = observer(() => {
  const counterStore = React.useContext(CounterStoreContext);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{counterStore.count}</Text>
            <Button
                title="Add"
                onPress={() => {
                    counterStore.addToCount();
                    console.log("count = ", counterStore.count);
                    
                }}
            />
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: "100%",
  },
  wrapper: {
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 425
  }
});

export default App;
```